# convert csv file to multiple nested json format

Tags: python

I have written a code to convert csv file to nested json format. I have multiple columns to be nested hence assigning separately for each column. The problem is I'm getting 2 fields for the same column in the json output.

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

csv_file = 'data.csv'
json_file = csv_file + '.json'

def main(input_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(input_file, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:
            row['TYPE'] = 'REVIEW',   # adding new key, value 
            row['RAWID'] = 1,
            row['CUSTOMER'] = {
                "ID": row['CUSTOMER_ID'],
                "NAME": row['CUSTOMER_NAME']
            }
            row['CATEGORY'] = {
                "ID": row['CATEGORY_ID'],
                "NAME": row['CATEGORY']
            }
            del (row["CUSTOMER_NAME"], row["CATEGORY_ID"], 
            row["CATEGORY"], row["CUSTOMER_ID"])   # deleting since fields coccuring twice
            csv_rows.append(row)

    with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(csv_rows, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        f.write('\n')
```

The output is as below:

```
[
{
    "CATEGORY": {
        "ID": "1", 
        "NAME": "Consumers"
    }, 
    "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
    "CUSTOMER_ID": "41",
    "CUSTOMER": {
        "ID": "41", 
        "NAME": "SA Port"
    },
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": "SA Port",
    "RAWID": [
        1 
    ]
}
]
```

I'm getting 2 entries for the fields I have assigned using row[''].

1. Is there any other way to get rid of this? I want only one entry for a particular field in each record.
2. Also how can I convert the keys to lower case after reading from csv.DictReader(). In my csv file all the columns are in upper case and hence I'm using the same to assign. But I want to convert all of them to lower case.

Comment: You can achieve this with json.dumps(mydata).

Comment: I tried with that but not getting any output.

Comment: I don't have your data (should create a proper [mcve]), so I had to create a dummy CSV file given your output. With that, however, I can't reproduce your results: all original columns (category_id, customer_id, customer_name, category_name) are not the json output.

Comment: Note that your currently listed program is incomplete (there is a syntaxerror because of a missing parentheses), and your output is also incomplete (missing closing delimiters). With that, I'm afraid all bets are off as to where the cause of your problem is.

Comment: I have missed those while copying here. I have not missed them while coding. and not getting any error as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert the keys to lower case, it would be simpler to generate a new dict per row. BTW, it should be enough to get rid of the duplicate fields:

```
    for row in reader:
        orow = collection.OrderedDict()
        orow['type'] = 'REVIEW',   # adding new key, value 
        orow['rawid'] = 1,
        orow['customer'] = {
            "id": row['CUSTOMER_ID'],
            "name": row['CUSTOMER_NAME']
        }
        orow['category'] = {
            "id": row['CATEGORY_ID'],
            "name": row['CATEGORY']
        }
        csv_rows.append(orow)
```